# Sort files into their Respective folders using Shell Scripting in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a few zip files inside **submissions** folder each containing multiple folders and files in them. I am required to extract the student ID from the name of zip file and make a target folder which will contain the C, Python and Java files from the extracted zip files according to their extensions. I have wrote a **recursive algorithm visit()** which takes the source directory and which is supposed to identify the file extensions after unzipping, rename them to main.c/main.py/Main.java and move them to target/C, target/Python and target/Java respectively but my code only unzips the contents into the **submissions** folder and does nothing else. I cannot figure out how to fix this problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create target directory
mkdir targets
# Create subdirectories for C, Python, and Java
mkdir targets/C
mkdir targets/Python
mkdir targets/Java
# Loop through all files in submissions directory
for file in submissions/*.zip
do
  # Extract the contents of the zip file
  unzip "$file" -d /home/goat/Desktop/Jaid/'CSE 314'/'Offline 1'/Workspace/submissions
  # Get the student ID from the file name
  student_id=${file: -11:7}
  #echo $student_id
  visit()
  {
    if [ -d $1 ]
    then
      for i in $1/*
      do
        visit "$i"
      done
    elif [ -f $1 ]
    then
      #echo $1
      # Get the file extension
      file_extension=${1: -1}
      # Check if the file extension is C, Python, or Java
      # for c
      if [ "$file_extension" == "c" ]
      then
        # Copy the C file to the targets/C directory
        cp "$1" targets/C/"$student_id"/main.c
      #for py
      elif [ "$file_extension" == "y" ]
      then
        # Copy the Python file to the targets/Python directory
        cp "$1" targets/Python/"$student_id"/main.py
      #for java
      elif [ "$file_extension" == "a" ]
      then
        # Copy the Java file to the targets/Java directory
        cp "$1" targets/Java/"$student_id"/Main.java
      fi
        fi
  }
  
  visit submissions


  # Remove the extracted files
  #rm -rf "$file"
done
```

Comment: First rule of debugging bash: `set -x`.  Without sample data to play w/ ...

Comment: Your code does things weirdly. You have a main loop which unpacks files from `.zip` files into the `submissions` directory, where the `.zip` files themselves are located.  Each time you unzip a file, you recursively process the `submissions` directory. That looks as if many files will be copied two or more times. Maybe you want to do all the unzipping first, and then call `visit` just once?

Answer (score 0):

I could finally fix my problem.

1. The visit function was called inappropriately and required two arguments: the source directory and the student ID.
2. The extraction code I wrote for extension **file_extension=${1: -1}** should be  **file_extension="${source##*.}"**

These 2 fixes solved my problem.